# Best way to compute the rank of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
 1&2&3&4&5\\6&7&8&9&10\\11&12&13&14&15\\16&17&18&19&20\\21&22&23&24&25\end{bmatrix}.$$

Which would be the best way to compute its rank?

I first thought about computing the determinant but then it seemed better to find its echelon form which would give me the rank. Is there a more efficient way?

I found out that the last three rows were spanned by the first two (So the rank is 2) but it was kind of a lucky thing so I can't expect to get it every time like that.

Comment: I would just observe that all the rows are linear combinations of $(1,2,3,4,5)$ and $(1,1,1,1,1)$ (the latter comes in multiples of five only). This shows that the row space is at most 2-dimensional. The two first rows are linearly independent so we are done.

Comment: also to be generated is not the correct word here. spanned is better.

Comment: Oh. Of course, Jyrki, that gives the desired result. Thanks.

Comment: @mathreadler Sorry, I am not used to differentiate between span an generate in English (In Spanish the word for both of them is "generar". Thanks.

Comment: @Nell : It is not a difference between the languages per se, in the english language you are probably right you can use generate to describe what you want to describe. But in different branches of mathematics they mean different things. In linear algebra something that can be written as a linear combination of something else is "spanned" by it. In abstract algebra something that can be written as a sequence of operations between elements of some small set is said to be "generated" by the set.

Comment: Someone knows why did guy delete? Is it not possible to switch field and retain properties in general? (I almost only work on $\mathbb R$ and $ \mathbb C$)

Comment: However when we say an ideal is generated by some set, it's the same span, just that as a $R-$module. The real difference is in generating sets for groups, $k-$algebras (Or field extensions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can notice that if $a=[1\ 2\ 3\ 4 \ 5]$ and $u=[1\ 1\ 1\ 1\ 1]$, then the matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
a + 5u \\
a + 10u \\
a + 15u \\
a + 20u
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and it is clear that the row space is generated by $a$ and $u$.

Comment: Bah, can you please go away to TeX ? I'm trying to score some points here :-)

Answer (score 3):

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
 1&2&3&4&5\\6&7&8&9&10\\11&12&13&14&15\\16&17&18&19&20\\21&22&23&24&25\end{bmatrix}.$$
Removing the first row from the third and last row . And removing the second row from the fourth row give $A$ in $\Bbb Z_2$ gives,

$$A'=\begin{bmatrix}
 1&2&3&4&5\\6&7&8&9&10\\10&10&10&10&10\\10&10&10&10&10\\20&20&20&20&20\end{bmatrix}.$$
Removing the first row to the second gives 
$$A''=\begin{bmatrix}
 1&2&3&4&5\\5&5&5&5&5\\10&10&10&10&10\\10&10&10&10&10\\20&20&20&20&20\end{bmatrix}.$$
then  $$rank (A )=rank (A')=rank (A'') = 2$$

Answer (score 1):

These are generalized cell phone keypad matrices, i.e., containg the consecutive numbers $1,2\ldots ,n^2$, for $n\ge 3$. The name comes from the case $n=3$:
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        4 & 5 & 6 \\
        7 & 8 & 9 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
They have rank $2$ for all $n\ge 3$, because adding the first and third row gives two times the second row, as we see directly here for $n=3$. This can be easily generalized to $n\times n$ hyper-cell phone matrices, for all $n\ge 3$. So you were not just lucky, but this always works.

Answer (score 1):

For such matrices you can always use the matrix of the form

$$
T = \begin{bmatrix}
1& 0& 0& 0& 0 \\
-1& 1& 0& 0& 0 \\
0& -1& 1& 0& 0 \\
0& 0& -1& 1& 0 \\
0& 0& 0& -1& 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

which is full rank and then $T^T A T$ will give you

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
 0&  0 & 0 & 0& -5\\
 0&  0 & 0 & 0& -5\\
 0&  0 & 0 & 0 &-5\\
 0&  0 & 0 & 0 &-5\\
-1& -1 &-1 &-1 &25
\end{bmatrix}
$$

In Python

```
import numpy as np
T = np.eye(5) - np.diag(np.ones(4),k=-1)
A = np.arange(1,26).reshape(5,5)
T.T @ A @ T
```

would give

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -5.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -5.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -5.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -5.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., 25.]])
```